# Ansible privilege escalation --become

Tags: ansible, command-line-interface, ansible-2.x

Once upon a time (I think before version 1.9) we could use **-s** for sudo on command line. Now it does not work. I am using version 2.85 on Ubuntu 18.04.

`$ ansible all -m apt -a “name=httpd state=latest”` - this should give error lack of privilege, but instead `ERROR! Extraneous options or arguments`

`$ ansible -s all -m apt -a “name=httpd state=latest”` - this used to work once upon a time. Also instead of `-s` tried  `-b` and `--become` - all give- **ERROR! Extraneous options or arguments**

Also tried `--become-user=root`  -  same error

Is this command line syntax wrong- *has all this changed over time*?

How do we solve this - just use playbooks?

**Update 1**
The quote issue copy paste out of ms word - in word somehow it converts " to “ - that is how that transformation happened. So just use notepad.

Now replaced `“ ”` with `" "` and `-b` option.
Tried this it went further
 `ansible -b all -m apt -a "name=httpd state=latest"`

**But it fails:**
    [WARNING]: Could not find aptitude. Using apt-get instead

`x.x.x.x | FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
    },
    "cache_update_time": 1570925983,
    "cache_updated": false,
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "'/usr/bin/apt-get -y -o \"Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef\" -o \"Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold\"      install 'httpd'' failed: E: Package 'httpd' has no installation candidate\n",
    "rc": 100,  ...`

Not sure what this error means means - "install 'httpd'' failed: E: Package 'httpd' has no installation candidate". The target machine is ubuntu 18.04

**This command works**
apache2 (for debian) with -b (for sudo):
`ansible -b all -m apt -a "name=apache2 state=latest"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that Ubuntu doesn't have a package named `httpd` which is explained in the error message here: `failed: E: Package 'httpd' has no installation candidate`

The Red Hat family of distros (RHEL, CentOS, and Fedora) calls it `httpd` because that's technically what the [upstream project name is](https://httpd.apache.org/), where as the Debian family of distros (which Ubuntu belongs to as a descendent of Debian) calls it `apache2` because in the heyday of the LAMP stack the `httpd` service was commonly known as simply "Apache" and we're currently on major revision 2.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to replace your quotes with simple double or single quote marks:

```sh
ansible all -m apt -a "name=httpd state=latest"
```

or

```sh
ansible all -m apt -a 'name=httpd state=latest'
```

Your shell probably isn't recognising the open/close quote marks you're using so ansible is getting `“name=httpd` as the argument to the `-a` option and doesn't know what to do with `state=latest”`.

Comment: _thanks for keen observation_. I have exactly one double quote key on my m/c " " - so whatever happened here- could be copy-paste issue. So I went past that. Once again `-s` option does not work (nor without it). `-b` option takes it further but still fails. Posting error in main post.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, httpd is called as apache2 in Ubuntu, so you can use the below command.

```
ansible all -m apt -a "name=apache2 state=latest"
```

Comment: It worked finally, But actually the command needs the **-b** option also `ansible -b all -m apt -a "name=apache2 state=latest"`.